# The most general procedure for quantization

Tags: quantum-field-theory, quantum-gravity, hamiltonian-formalism, quantization

I recently read the following passage on page 137 in volume I of 'Quantum Fields and Strings: A course for Mathematicians' by Pierre Deligne and others (note that I am no mathematician and have not gotten too far into reading the book, so bear with me):

> *A physical system is usually described in terms of states and observable. In the Hamiltonian framework of classical mechanics, the states form a symplectic manifold $(M,\omega)$ and the observables are functions on $M$. The dynamics of a (time invariant) system is a one parameter group of symplectic diffeomorphisms; the generating function is the energy or Hamiltonian. The system is said to be free if $(M,\omega)$ is an affine symplectic space and the motion is by a one-parameter group of symplectic transformations. This general descriptions applies to any system that includes classical particles, fields, strings and other types of objects.*

The last sentence, in particular, has really intrigued me. It implies a most general procedure for quantizing all systems encountered in physics. I haven't understood the part on symplectic diffeomorphisms or free systems. Here are my questions:

1. Given a constraint-free phase-space, equipped with the symplectic 2-form, we can construct a Hilbert space of states and a set of observables and start calculating expectation values and probability amplitudes. Since the passage says that this applies to point particles, fields and strings, I assume this is all there is to quantization of any system. Is this true?
2. What is the general procedure for such a construction, given $M$ and $\omega$?
3. For classical fields and strings what does this symplectic 2-form look like? (isn't it of infinite dimension?)
4. Also I assume for constrained systems like in loop quantum gravity, one needs to solve for the constraints and cast the system as a constraint-free before constructing the phase, am I correct?
5. I don't know what 'the one-parameter group of symplectic diffeomorphisms' are. How are the different from ordinary diffeomorphisms on a manifold? Since diffeomorphisms may be looked at as a tiny co-ordinate changes, are these diffeomorphisms canonical transformations? (is time or its equivalent the parameter mentioned above?)
6. What is meant by a 'free' system as given above?
7. By 'affine' I assume they mean that the connection on $M$ is flat and torsion free, what would this physically mean in the case of a one dimensional-oscillator or in the case of systems with strings and fields?
8. In systems that do not permit a Lagrangian description, how exactly do we define the cotangent bundle necessary for the conjugate momenta? If we can't, then how do we construct the symplectic 2-form? If we can't construct the symplectic 2-form, then how do we quantize the system?

I have asked a lot of long questions, so please answer as many as you can and link relevant articles.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The overall idea is the following. As the symplectic manifold is affine (in the sense of affine spaces not in the sense of the existence of an affine connection), when you fix a point $O$, the manifold becomes a real vector space equipped with a non-degenerate symplectic form. A quantization procedure is nothing but the assignment of a (Hilbert-) **Kahler structure** completing the symplectic structure. In this way the real vector space becomes a complex vector space equipped with a Hermitian scalar product and its completion is a **Hilbert space** where one defines the quantum theory. As I shall prove shortly in the subsequent example, symplectic symmetries becomes unitary symmetries provided the Hilbert-Kahler structure is invariant under the symmetry. In this way time evolution in Hamiltonian description gives rise to a unitary time evolution.

An interesting example is the following.  Consider a smooth  **globally hyperbolic spacetime** $M$ and the real vector space $S$ of **smooth real solutions** $\psi$ of **real Klein-Gordon equation** such that they have **compactly supported Cauchy data** (on one and thus every Cauchy surface of the spacetime).

A non-degenerate (well defined) **symplectic form** is given by:    $$\sigma(\psi,\phi) := \int_\Sigma (\psi \nabla_a \phi - \phi \nabla_a \psi)\: n^a d\Sigma   $$
where $\Sigma$ is a smooth spacelike Cauchy surface, $n$ its normalized normal vector future pointing and $d\Sigma$ the standard volume form induced by the metric of the spacetime. In view of the KG equation the choice of $\Sigma$ does not matter as one can easily prove using the divergence theorem.

There are infinitely many Kahler structures one can build up here. A procedure (one of the possible ones) is to define a real scalar product:
$$\mu : S \times S \to R$$
such that $\sigma$ is **continuous** with respect to it (the factor $4$ arises for pure later convenience):
$$|\sigma(\psi, \phi)|^2 \leq 4\mu(\psi,\psi)  \mu(\psi,\psi)\:.$$
Under this hypotheses a Hilbert-Kahler structure can be defined as I go to summarize.

It is possible to prove that there exist a complex Hilbert space $H$ and an injective $R$-linear map $K: S \to H$ such that $K(S)+ i K(S)$ is dense in $H$ and, if $\langle | \rangle$ denotes the Hilbert space product:
$$\langle K\psi | K\phi \rangle = \mu(\psi,\phi) -\frac{i}{2}\sigma(\psi,\phi) \quad \forall \psi, \phi \in S\:.$$
Finally the pair $(H,K)$ is determined up to unitary isomorphisms form the triple $(S, \sigma, \mu)$.

You see that, as a matter of fact, $H$ is a Hilbertian complexfication of $S$ whose antisymmetric part of the scalar product is the symplectic form. (It is also possible to write down the **almost complex structure** of the theory that is related with the polar decomposition of the operator representing $\sigma$ in the closure of the real vector space $S$ equipped with the real scalar product $\mu$.)

What is the **physical meaning** of $H$?

It is that the physicists call **one-particle Hilbert space**. Indeed consider the **bosonic Fock Space**, ${\cal F}_+(H)$, generated by $H$.

$${\cal F}_+(H)= C \oplus H \oplus (H\otimes H)_S \oplus (H\otimes H\otimes H)_S \oplus \cdots\:,$$
and we denote by $|vac_\mu\rangle$ the number $1$ in $C$ viewed as a vector in ${\cal F}_+(H)$

One may define of ${\cal F}_+(H)$ a faithful representation of bosonic **CCR** by defining the **field operator**:

$$\Phi(\psi) := a_{K\psi} + a^*_{K\psi}$$

where $a_f$ is the standard annihilation operator referred to the vector $f\in H$ and $a_f^*$ the standard creation operator referred to the vector $f\in H$.
It turns out that, with that definition the vacuum expectation values:
$$\langle vac_\mu| \Phi(\psi_1)\cdots \Phi(\psi_n) |vac_\mu\rangle $$ 
satisfy the standard Wick's prescription and thus all them can be computed in terms of the **two-point function** only:
$$\langle vac_\mu| \Phi(\psi) \Phi(\phi) |vac_\mu\rangle $$
Moreover they are in agreement with the formula valid for **Gaussian states** (like free Minkowski vacuum in Minkowski spacetime)
$$ \langle vac_\mu | e^{i \Phi(\psi)} |vac_\mu \rangle = e^{-\mu(\psi,\psi)/2}$$

Actually, in view of the GNS theorem the constructed representation of the CCR is uniquely determined by $\mu$, up to unitary equivalences.

The field operator $\Phi$ is smeared with KG solutions instead of smooth supportly compacted functions $f$ as usual. However the "translation" is simply obtained. If $E : C_0^{\infty}(M) \to S$ denotes the **causal propagator** (the difference of the advanced and retarded fundamental solution of KG equation) the usual field operator smeared with $f\in C_0^{\infty}(M)$ is:
$$\hat{\phi}(f) := \Phi(Ef)\:.$$

The CCR can be stated in both languages. Smearing fields with KG solutions one has:

$$[\Phi(\psi), \Phi(\phi)] = i \sigma(\psi,\phi)I\:,$$

smearing field operators with functions, one instead has:

$$[\hat{\phi}(f), \hat{\phi}(g)] = i E(f,g) I$$

Every **one-parameter group of symplectic diffeomorphisms** $\alpha_t :S \to S$ (for instance continuous Killing isometries of $M$) give rise to an action on the algebra of the quantum fields
$$\alpha^*_t(\Phi(\psi)) := \Phi(\psi \circ \alpha_t)\:.$$
If the state $|vac_\mu\rangle$ is **invariant** under $\alpha_t$, namely 
$$\mu\left(\psi \circ \alpha_t,\psi \circ \alpha_t\right) = \mu\left(\psi ,\psi \right)\quad \forall t \in R,$$
then, essentially using Stone's theorem, one sees that the said continuous symmetry admits a (strongly continuous) unitary representation:
$$U_t \Phi(\psi) U^*_t =\alpha^*_t(\Phi(\psi))\:.$$
The self-adjoint generator of $U_t= e^{-itH}$ is an Hamiltonian operator for that symmetry. Actually this interpretation is suitable if $\alpha_t$ arises by a timelike continuous Killing symmetry. Minkowki vacuum is constructed in this way requiring that the corresponding $\mu$ is invariant under the whole orthochronous Poincaré group.

All the picture I have sketched  is intermediate between the "practical" QFT and the so-called **algebraic formulation**. I only would like to stress that choosing different $\mu$ one generally obtain **unitarily inequivalent** representations of bosonic CCR.

Comment: +1, Informative answer (though OP likely doesn't know Kähler). / Does the same work if you view classical mechanics as a field theory over the $\mathbb R$ time axis? / You pop out one concise definition after the other and it seems to work. What are general obstacles to have injective *and* dense $K$? For computational purposes, this map seems essentially bijective. Does one need to know much about solving the classical equations of motion (Klein Gordon here, although it's never used in your answer as far as I can see) to find the right Hilber space of could one start ad hoc on the other side?

Comment: It works on every manifold of course, I think it works with classical mechanics, but I never tried to do it. $K$ is always injective because $\sigma$ is non-degenerate (the proof is trivial). It is possible to prove that $K$ is dense (*not* $K+iK$) **if and only if** the state on the  CCR $^*$-algebra is **pure** (i.e. extremal). Actually the classical equation do not play a fundamental role, the crucial object is the symplectic structure that, here, arises from the classical equation of motion.

Comment: There is no a "right" Hilbert space: roughly speaking, you have as many Hilbert spaces as many the scalar products $\mu$ are. At most a "right" Hilbert space can be fixed by requiring that it supports certain unitary representations of symmetry groups. And it is done by requiring that $\mu$ is invariant under the corresponding symplectic symmetries.

Comment: I do not think there is something like Darboux' theorem when you consider infinite dimensional symplectic spaces. It is better to think of the symplectic form, even in the finite dimensional case, as an antisymmetric non-degenerate map $\omega : TM\times TM \to R$ without fixing a preferred coordinate system to describe it. Essentially $M$ identifies with its tangent space at a point $T_pM$ as $M$ is supposed to be affine.

Comment: OK. The vector space $V$ is that of the 2n-ple $(x^1,\ldots,x^n,p_1,\ldots,p_n)$. You have to define a real symmetric scalar product $\mu$ on $V$ that satisfies (I used an apparently weaker requirement in my answer, but is equivalent to this if $V$ is finite dimensional) $4\mu(z,z) = \max_{z'\neq 0} |\sigma(z,z')|^2/\mu(z',z')$. With these choices one sees that there is a complex vector space $H$ (subspace of $V+iV$) equipped with an Hermitean scalar product  and a $R$-linear map $K: V \to H$ that verifies the two conditions I wrote in my answer (actually $K(V)=H$ in this case).

Comment: Going on with the Fock space construction, one sees that this space is that of the harmonic oscillator that, in turn is isomorphic to $L^2(R)$.

Comment: @drake Haag's textbook does not deal with this stuff. Wald's book you mentioned is a good first reference, not very elaborated from a mathematical viewpoint. Kay-Wald's Report of thermal states and bifurcate Killing horizon contains a nice account of this procedure for quantum fields. I very concise summary (mathematically advanced actually) can be found in the appendix B of this long paper of mine http://arxiv.org/abs/arXiv:0907.1034

Comment: Thanks, I think your answer above is more useful for me. Questions: 1) What makes systems with finite degrees of freedom to essentially have just one $\mu$ (all the representations of the CCR are related by unitary transformations)? 2) What changes if the Hamiltonian explicitly depends on time? 3) Are gauge symmetries implemented in a different way? How? 4) Are anomalies symplectic symmetries for which there is no invariant $\mu$? Let me know which points deserve a separate question. Thanks.

Comment: 1) just the fact that state space is finite dimensional and the so called **Stone-von Neumann theorem** that holds in this case. 2) The basic construction has nothing to do with a choice of a Hamiltonian. Perhaps you are referring to a generator of continuous symmetries? It could parametrically depend on some external time (the parameter of another Killing symmetry, as the boost does, there is no problem in principle. 3) To be honest: I do not know, I never tackled that problem. 4) I did not understand, could you add further details to your question?

Comment: Concerning (1) I perhaps answered re-formulating your question! You asked how SvN theorem arises in this formalism. Actually I never considered it as I mostly deal with the infinite dimensional case. I guess that it should be related with the requirement $4\mu(z,z)= \max_{z'\neq 0}|\sigma(z,z')|^2/\mu(z',z')$. Probably it implies that $\mu$ is unique up to a symplectic transformation. I suppose that Wald consider this issue in the introductory (finite dimensional) part of the construction. I do not have a copy of that book now.

Comment: Grazie mille! 1) Yes, I was asking about S-vN in this context. 2) I thought there were subtleties when the Hamiltonian depended on time. I'd have to rethink it. I barely remember it was related to the possibility of changing the hamiltonian through explicitly time-dependent canonical transformations. For example, if I remember correctly, a Klein-Gordon field in a Friedman-Robertson spacetime is related to a Klein-Gordon field with a time-dependent mass in Minkowski space through a canonical transformation.

Comment: The quantum theory and the implementation of a unitary evolution depend on the field description one uses. 4) Yes, absolutely. How do *anomalies* arise in this formalism? You could perhaps  add an answer to this question about anomalies http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/33195/classical-and-quantum-anomalies

Comment: 1) the condition I wrote implies that the rep of CCR is irreducuble (the state is pure), this is a fundamental requirement in S-vN theorem, so I guess that it is the crucial one. 2) I did not want to say that Hamiltonians depending on time are treated in a simpler manner here, the problems are more or less the same as in the standard approach. BTW it is possible to re-formulate Dyson's series and its UV renormalization at completely algebraic level generalizing Epstein-Glaser procedure. 4) Concerning anomalies everything depend on their nature.

Comment: Some, in QFT are covariant and do not depend on the state (in a certain class of states said of Hadamard form), the trace anomaly is an example. These can be treated at algebraic level. Take into account that the algebraic formulation includes the standard one by means of the GNS theorem, so you can find here all that you find within the standard formulation.

Comment: Hi.This is not the best way to contact you, but http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/228043/canonical-second-quantization-vs-canonical-quantization-with-multisymplectic-for?noredirect=1#comment494185_228043 is related to your answer @ValterMoretti . Any idea?

Comment: @user40276 Sorry I am being very busy these days  with a paper we are finishing and your question seems to be quite technical (I tried to read it...unsuccessfully). I hope someone other will be able to help you. I will try to come back to your issue in the future...

Comment: I'm really confused because I don't know many of these terms. You started with the symplectic geometry formulation of classical field theory (you had a phase space of Klein Gordon solutions on a hypersurface $\Sigma$ and a symplectic form for the dynamics). You then defined an inner product $\mu$ of the phase space configurations. Then you said that this structure implies a Hilbert space structure whose inner product corresponds to $\mu-\frac{i}{2}\sigma$. Is this correct? Does this mean that classical mechanics also has a complex Hilber space structure?

Comment: I do not remember well details. After all  I wrote that answer more than 8 years ago. However yes, in the sense that you can costruct a Hilbert space structure on every real symplectic space. In the case of classical mechanics in $R^{2}$, with a suitable choice of $\mu$ you find the operators $X$ and $P$ in terns of $a$ and $a^\dagger$.

Comment: Much thanks for the reply. Please link me a proof of this. Also, does the symplectic form become a Moyal bracket for the Quantum case? And is the need for $\mu$ related to the need to have probability/qualsiprobability phase space distributions?

Answer (score 7):

Here are some comments on the literature, maybe serving to put Valter Moretti's more concrete response into a broader perspective.

The question asked is a surprisingly good question. It is "good", because it is indeed true that there is this very general prescription for quantization; and "surprisingly" because, while the general idea has been around for ages, this has been understood in decent generality only last year!

Namely, on the one hand it is long appreciated in the context of quantum mechanics that what physicists sweepingly call "canonical quantization" is really this: the construction of the [covariant phase space](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/phase+space) as a (pre-)symplectic manifold, and then the quantization this by the prescription of either [algebraic deformation quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/deformation%20quantization) or [geometric quantization](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/geometric%20quantization).

In contrast, it has been understood only surprisingly more recently that established methods of perturbative quantization of field theories, especially in the guise of Epstein-Glaser's [causal peruturbation theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/causal%20perturbation%20theory) (such as QED, QCD, and also perturbative quantum gravity, as in Scharf's textbooks) are indeed also examples of this general method.

For free fields (no interactions), this was first understood in

- J. Dito. "Star-product approach to quantum field theory: The free scalar
  field". Letters in Mathematical Physics, 20(2):125–134, 1990.

and then amplified in a long series of articles on [locally covariant perturbative quantum field theory](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locally+covariant+perturbative+quantum+field+theory)

by Klaus Fredenhagen and collaborators, starting with

- M. Dütsch and K. Fredenhagen. "Perturbative algebraic field theory, and deformation quantization". In R. Longo (ed), "Mathematical Physics in Mathematics and Physics, Quantum and Operator Algebraic Aspects", volume 30 of Fields Institute Communications, pages 151–160. American Mathematical Society, 2001.

Curiously, despite this insight, these authors continued to treat interacting quantum field theory by the comparatively ad hoc Bogoliubov formula, instead of similarly deriving it from a quantization of the (pre-)symplectic structure of the phase space of the interacting theory.

That last step, to show that the traditional construction of interacting peturbative quantum field theory via time-ordered products and Bogoliubov's formula also follows from the general prescription of deformation/geometric quantization of (pre-)symplectic phase space was made, unbelievably, only last year, in the highly recommendable thesis

- Giovanni Collini,  ***Fedosov Quantization and Perturbative Quantum Field Theory*** [arXiv:1603.09626](https://arxiv.org/abs/1603.09626)

Just read the introduction of this thesis, it is very much worthwhile.

(I learned about this article from Igor Khavkine and Alexander Schenkel for which I am grateful.)

In a similar spirit a little later appeared

- Eli Hawkins, Kasia Rejzner, The Star Product in Interacting Quantum Field Theory [arxiv:1612.09157](https://arxiv.org/abs/1612.09157)

which disucsses the situation in a bit more generality than Collini does, but omitting the technical details of renormalization in this perspective.

Answer (score 1):

I will give you a more general answer, in fact, a very mathematical answer that defines quantization.

Setup:
k is a characteristic 0 field, and K = k[[h]]

#### Deformation

A Deformation algebra is a topologically free K-algebra, so by definition if you have some associative K-algebra $A_0$, a *deformation* of $A_0$ is a deformation algebra $A$ s.t. $A_0 = A/hA$.

Now consider $A_0$ being commutative (A not necessarily). Then, $A_0$ inherits a Poisson Structure from $A$.

Let multiplication in $A$ be *. Then for $f_0,g_0 \in A_0$, by choosing arbitrary listings $f,g$, we have $f *g - g*f = 0\ (mod\ h)$

We set $$\{f_0,g_0\} = \frac{1}{h} (f*g - g*f)\ (mod\ h)$$

You can see that $(A_0,\{,\})$ is indeed a Poisson algebra.

This Poisson algebra is the **quasiclassical limit of $A$**, and $A$ is the **quantization of $A_0$**.

Here you can see how quasiclassical limit and quantization are processes that are in a way inverse, with a few caveats:

- The Quasiclassical Limit is **unique and well defined**
- Quantization is in general **non-unique** and there exist Poisson algebras that admit no quantization.

#### Moyal-Weyl Quantization

The famous deformation quantization of Moyal and Weyl is an example of this.

Here $A_0 = [k,p]$ with the classical Poisson Structure, and we have

$$f*g = m(exp(\frac{1}{2}h(\partial_{[x} \otimes \partial_{,p]})), f \otimes f)$$ where $m:A_0 \otimes A_0 \rightarrow A_0$ is the multiplication.

#### Important Theorems

*Theorem 1 (Symplectic Manifold Local Quantization)*

Any symplectic Manifold admits a local quantization. (construction via cotangent bundle.

*Theorem 2 (Groenwald)*

Let $A$ be a quantization of $A_0 =\mathcal{C}^
{\infty}(M)$. There is **no** homomorphism $$\Phi : SDiff(M)\rightarrow Aut(A)$$

such that $\Phi = \Phi_0 \ (mod\ h)$

The Groenwald theorem is a very famous No go theorem that says that symmetry is broken by quantization.

This is bad news for symplectic manifolds and associative K-algebras, but worry not, as *Poisson-Lie Groups* do not suffer from this theorem's implications.

#### Poisson Manifolds

Kontsevich made the brilliant discovery of the theorem that states that **any Poisson Manifold, admits a local quantization**.

A celebrated example is geometric quantization.

#### Familiar Notions in Physics

These facts lead to the basic statement that Quantum Mechanics becomes Classical Mechanics in the **quasiclassical limit**, where now the formal variable h is $\hbar$.

Let me now give an example to make it a bit more clear.

#### Example

Take $M = T^* \Bbb R$ with coordinates $(x,p)$ and the usual Poisson structure.

The Hamiltonian is given by $H = \frac{p^2}{2m} + V(x)$, and we have the usual Hamilton's equations.

Now from polynomial deformation quantization, we know that the quantization of the Poisson Algebra $C^\infty _{pol} (T^* \Bbb R)$ is

$$A = (\bigoplus_{n \geq 0} h^n \mathcal{D}^n_{\Bbb R})[[h]]$$

This quantization has a polynomial rational form and defines a family of algebras $A(\hbar)$. Such an algebra is an algebra of polynomial differential operators on $C^\infty (\Bbb R)$ when $\hbar \neq 0$, and $A(0) = C^\infty _{pol} (T^* \Bbb R)$. The algebra $A = A(\hbar)$ acts on the Hilbert Space $L^2(\Bbb R)$.  The position coordinate and momentum coordinates are the famous quantum operators, and the Hamiltonian takes don't he famous form of

$$\hat{H} = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2} d_x^2 + V(x)$$

and the evolution equations become

$$i\hbar \frac{dQ}{dt} = [- \frac{\hbar^2}{2} d_x^2 + V(x),Q]\ \ Q \in A$$

---

Sources: Etingof, Schiffmann: "Lectures on Quantum Groups"