# Clarification on the 11 dimension in the M-theory

Tags: string-theory, spacetime, spacetime-dimensions, compactification

In the book the Grand Design by Stephen Hawking, he wrote about  the [M-theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M-theory), and how in that theory it has 11 dimensions. I do not quite get that, so can someone explain it to me a little bit. I understand four dimension is where space and time combine together, and there is no movement in four dimensional space because an event over time is represented by a line. I get that, but I do not quite understand how 11 dimension works, so I would really appreciate if anyone could help me understand this concept.

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10527/2451 and links therein.

Comment: That's really a rather broad question, and perhaps impossible to answer in a way that is both understandable to you and correct. A useful answer would involve *first* explaining the ten dimensions of superstring theories and then explaining why an eleven-dimensional theory called M-theory is believed to exist that "connects" there, which really amounts to a textbook. For a general discussion of extra dimensions, [see here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/10527/50583), for a specific discussions of 10d in string theory, see [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/31882/50583)

Comment: At the smallest scales, instead of being able to move forward/back along three orthogonal axes (and forward through time), you are able to move forward/backward along ten orthogonal axes (and forward through time). Easy peasy!

Comment: Read the link Qmechanic has listed  above, and Google  a free e-book , using the keywords String Theory For Dummies Pdf. The book is very good, it tells you why some people like string theory and what it's drawbacks are.