# What areas of physics depend on the sum $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6+ 7+\ldots= -1/12$?

Tags: mathematics, regularization

This youtube video from Numberphile, http://youtu.be/w-I6XTVZXww

shows how the value is derived. In the video, one interviewee claims that "this result is used in many areas of physics". In the video, only string theory is mentioned.

Which areas of physics use or depend on the sum $$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6+ 7+\ldots= -1/12?$$

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a joke (although I haven't seen the video).

Comment: @ike It’s not a joke.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does the sum of the series “1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6…” to infinity = “-1/12”?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/92739/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Critical Dimension of Bosonic Strings and Regularization of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66371/)

Comment: See my answer to: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/105063/ for an example of its use in string theory.

Comment: Just to be clear, though this result is valid, the way it is "derived" in the Numberphile video is completely incorrect. See: http://scientopia.org/blogs/goodmath/2014/01/17/bad-math-from-the-bad-astronomer/

Answer (score 5):

The sum $1+2+3+4+\ldots$ is not *equal to* $\frac{-1}{12}$. The series is divergent, and tends towards infinity, as the cameraman speculated near the start of the video.

However, $\frac{-1}{12}$ can be *associated with* the series $1+2+3+4+\ldots$, for example with analytic continuation. To quote the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_continuation) on the subject:

> Analytic continuation often succeeds in defining further values of a function, for example in a new region where an infinite series representation in terms of which it is initially defined becomes divergent.

Evelyn Lamb (mathematics postdoc, University of Utah) wrote a blog article for [Scientific American](http://blogs.scientificamerican.com/roots-of-unity/2014/01/20/is-the-sum-of-positive-integers-negative/) about this very video. Tony Padilla (the man explaining the "proof" in the video) writes about the series [with more rigor](http://www.nottingham.ac.uk/~ppzap4/response.html) on his own webpage. For more information, a question on math.SE would be appropriate.

As far as the physics goes, the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF#Physics) on the series goes into some detail, including bosonic string theory, the Goddard–Thorn theorem, and computing the Casimir force for a scalar field. However, I'm not familiar enough with the subject to expand on it. For more information, a question on physics.SE would be appropriate. *(This answer was written while the question was still on skeptics.SE)*