# Why string theorist use the following result?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, regularization

$1+2+3.......$so on $ = -1/12.$ I have seen a few proofs of this result. And I hope most of you are familiar with them.

- Why string theorist use this ambiguous result in string theory, when assigning a value to a divergent sum is not acceptable to many mathematician?

  - If this result is true; does it consolidate the belief that nature of ultimate reality cannot be perceivable by human mind.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Critical Dimension of Bosonic Strings and Regularization of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n$](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/66371/) and linked questions there.

Comment: See also [Terry Tao's blog](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/04/10/the-euler-maclaurin-formula-bernoulli-numbers-the-zeta-function-and-real-variable-analytic-continuation/) for a more or less rigorous mathematical treatment of this kind of regularisation.

Comment: Read the "Divergent Series" chapter of Kline's History of Mathematics to see how infinite sums like these represent asymptotic approximations to well-defined functions :)